# Hibernate could not locate named parameter even if it exist

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, named-parameters

Hibernate Keeps detecting

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [name]
```

even though it exist. here's my hql

```
Query query = sess().createQuery("from UserProfile where firstName LIKE '%:name%'").setParameter("name", name);
```

Why does hibernate keeps throwing that exception? even though the parameter exist?

Comment: I guess you don't need those quotas around parameter, this could case your problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
Query query = sess().createQuery("from UserProfile where firstName LIKE :name")
                    .setParameter("name", "%"+name+"%");
```

In your case `':name'` is actual string Hibernate will search for. If you need to have a real named parameter, you need to have just `:name`.

Thus `%` should be passed as a value of `:name` and Hibernate will substitute `:name` with actual value.

Note, that if your value contains `%` and you want it to be an actual letter instead of wildcard, you'll have to escape it, [here is](http://fisheye.jtalks.org/browse/~br=master/Poulpe/poulpe-model/src/main/java/org/jtalks/poulpe/model/dao/utils/SqlLikeEscaper.java?r=4e390d7d4e1ed18701d2e2463fc693b7ed367819) an example of escaper-class.

Comment: What is the diffference between String someName = "%"+name+"%"; and setParameter("name", "%"+name+"%"); and setParameter("name", someName ); ??

Comment: Hibernate just doesn't recognize that there is a named parameter, it doesn't know %:blah syntax. Same in SQL if you try to write LIKE '%?', it won't recognize it correctly. In case you have :name - this is a clear named parameter and you specify %blah as a string that database should look for. In case you have % as a value, you'll have to escape it.

Comment: it finally worked i just wanted to have an understand what's their difference, any link for more information regarding this issue?

Comment: I tried to describe this in more details in actual answer. I don't have any particular link to share, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

try to concatenate it using `hql`

```
"from UserProfile where firstName LIKE '%' || :name || '%'"
```

or using `CONCAT`

```
"from UserProfile where firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', :name ,'%')"
```

- [HQL CONCAT](http://thecafetechno.com/tutorials/hibernate/hql-concat-trim-function-example/)